# Does Java 10's newly added support for Docker include support for other container technologies?

Tags: java, docker, linux-containers, java-10

Improvements for running a JVM in Docker are awesome additions to Java 10.

Some of the improvements I am referring to are:

- memory limits set by the container
- available cpus set by the container
- cpu constraints set by the container
- the ability for the JVM to *know* it is running in a container

Does anyone know if these improvements are specific to *just* Docker, or can they be realized using other containers such as Warden, rkt, and/or others?

Comment: Looks like it's an ongoing project: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8182070

Comment: AFAIK the container support is not Docker specific but it is tied to Linux `cgroups`.

Comment: @apophis you are right and this counts as an answer btw IMO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much all container runtimes on linux are just rube goldberg machines - docker is one of those contraptions - built from the same low level building blocks: namespaces, cgroups, capabilities, virtual network devices and various other kernel features.

The JVM probes those underlying features and thus is mostly independent of the abstractions sitting above that. I say mostly because it may rely on things like procfs being present in the mount namespace to do the probing and in principle containers without those can be created.